# Fitting a thermostatic radiator valve head

Tags: heating, radiator

All my radiators in the house have thermostatic valves apart from one (which is a different style of radiator so I think it was probably fitted at a later date)

Looking at the photo I think the thermostatic head should go on the right (I think this is the return flow?)
[image]

and I’m looking to buy just the head.

They all seem to say they fit M30 x 1.5mm threads. ([For example](https://www.screwfix.com/p/drayton-rt212-white-trv-sensing-head/569hg)) I’ve measured everything on the right valve and can’t see anything that measures that size, but it also says that’s standard
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most/all US piping measurements are for the insides/internal pipe size/diameter, not the outside.  No knowledge if metric does it the same, but think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've realised, if you want a thermostatic radiator valve (TRV) on that radiator, you need to replace the entire valve. What you have now is a lockshield valve which can take either a smooth cap that locks it into a given position or a cap that will allow you to adjust the valve manually. To replace the valve, you would need to drain the whole central heating system (I would recommend waiting until winter is behind us).

These days, many TRVs are bidirectional and can go on the flow or return. Check the instructions before you buy. Some of them have a sort of switch that you can rotate to select the direction of flow.

Before fitting a TRV, make sure that your system will support having TRVs on all radiators. I *think* that most combi boilers these days have a built in bypass and won't get damaged if all the valves are shut but it's worth checking. In addition, boilers that are controlled by a thermostat often forego a TRV on the radiator closest to the thermostat. This is to avoid the situation where valves are all turned off but the house is cold: the boiler keeps firing but never makes the house any warmer. Depending on the type of boiler controls you have, this may or may not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that isnt a thermostatic valve. Thermostatic valves have a pin that moves freely up and down.

The picture shows a regular manual radiator valve with no turn knob